# Filtering multiple selected filed in PHP before uploading

Tags: javascript, php, html

I currently have a PHP script that uploads multiple files selected to a certain folder, I was able to filter the size and file extension if I will just upload a single file. In my case I do upload more than 1 file. here is my code below:

```js
foreach($_FILES['userfile']['error'] as $k=>$v)
 {
  $uploadfile = 'upload/'. basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$k]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
    {
        echo "File : ", $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$k] ," is valid, and was successfully uploaded.<br>";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "File : ", $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$k], " invalid file or file size out of range.<br>";
    }
 }
```

I want to filter each file extension before uploading. hope anyone can help me with this. thanks!

Comment: Where are the checks?

Comment: i still don't have the checks. i've tried searching but all i get is filtering for single files.

Comment: i want to filter the extension (e.g. .mp3 .txt) of the files before uploading it and filter the size too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$formats = array("mp3","txt");
$limit = 10485760;  

foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["name"] as $f => $name) {  

    // Filter format

    if (!in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $formats)
        $message[] = "$name is not a valid format!";
        continue; 
    }

    // Filter size

    if ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"][$f] > $limit) {
        $message[] = "$name exceeds size limit!";
        continue; 
    }

    // Upload file

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$f], "upload/".$name)){
        $message[] = "$name uploaded successfully!";
    }else{
        $message[] = "$name upload failed!";
    }
}
```